# install spree error, rails 3 , ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am new to ruby on rails. I follow the following links to install spree. but when run bundle exec rake spree_sample:load --trace , face errors. anybody can help?

http://guides.spreecommerce.com/getting_started.html

```
mingo@cxm:~/rails/spreetest$ bundle exec rake spree_sample:load --trace
DEPRECATION WARNING: class_inheritable_attribute is deprecated, please use class_attribute method instead. Notice their behavior are slightly different, so refer to class_attribute documentation first. (called from /home/mingo/rails/spreetest/config/application.rb:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: class_inheritable_attribute is deprecated, please use class_attribute method instead. Notice their behavior are slightly different, so refer to class_attribute documentation first. (called from /home/mingo/rails/spreetest/config/application.rb:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: class_inheritable_attribute is deprecated, please use class_attribute method instead. Notice their behavior are slightly different, so refer to class_attribute documentation first. (called from /home/mingo/rails/spreetest/config/application.rb:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: class_inheritable_attribute is deprecated, please use class_attribute method instead. Notice their behavior are slightly different, so refer to class_attribute documentation first. (called from /home/mingo/rails/spreetest/config/application.rb:7)
rake aborted!
Fixtures is not a class
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/spree_core-0.30.1/lib/custom_fixtures.rb:3
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/spree_core-0.30.1/lib/tasks/core.rake:2
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:397:in `load_tasks'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:397:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:397:in `load_tasks'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:395:in `load_tasks'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application/railties.rb:8:in `all'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:395:in `load_tasks'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:99:in `load_tasks'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/home/mingo/rails/spreetest/Rakefile:7
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:495:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:61:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32
/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/rake:19
mingo@cxm:~/rails/spreetest$
```

Comment: May I ask: How did you get Spree 0.30.1 installed when the latest is 0.60.2?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the edge version of Spree with Rails 3.1. Add this to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'spree', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree.git'
```

Also, I think edge Spree is only compatible with one of the latest Rails 3.1.1 release candidates. You may need to add this to your Gemfile as well:

```
gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git', :tag => "v3.1.1.rc1"
```

Comment: when i tried that, bundle install gave me:

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails"
\n   In Gemfile:
\n    spree (>= 0) ruby depends on
\n      rails (= 3.1.1) ruby
\n   rails (3.1.1.rc1)

Comment: Can you update your question with the contents of your Gemfile ? I don't get why you have two version of Rails in there.

Comment: i didn't have two versions of rails in gemfile, what i posted was output of "bundle install" when trying to use a solution in your answer. i think edge version of Spree (currently 0.70) now uses rails 3.1.1, not 3.1.1rc1, that's why i had an error. solved it now by installing spree 0.70 and rails 3.1.1